# How to use 'Mantle'

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

This is My Model :

```
@interface ZpCouncilVClrAppListModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic , assign) long long theId ; // 应用编号
@property (nonatomic , assign) NSUInteger index ; // 应用名称
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *name ; // 顺序号
@property (nonatomic , assign) NSInteger version ; // 最新版本号
@end

@interface ZpCouncilVClrCenterAdvModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *title ; // 标题
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *imageUrl ; // 图片URL
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *toUrl ; // 链接地址URL
@end

@interface ZpCouncilVClrNewsListModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *title ; // 标题
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *imageUrl ; // 图片
@property (nonatomic , assign) NSTimeInterval createDate ; // 时间
@end

@interface ZpCouncilVClrTopAdvModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *title ; // 标题
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *imageUrl ; // 图片URL
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *toUrl ; // 链接地址URL
@end

@interface ZpCouncilVClrModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSArray<ZpCouncilVClrAppListModel *>* appList ;
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSArray<ZpCouncilVClrCenterAdvModel *>* centerAdv ;
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSArray<ZpCouncilVClrNewsListModel *>* newsList ;
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSArray<ZpCouncilVClrTopAdvModel *>* topAdv ;
+ (ZpCouncilVClrModel *)createModelWith:(NSDictionary *)jsonParams ;
@end
```

This is implement :

```
@implementation ZpCouncilVClrAppListModel
+(NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{@"theId":@"id"} ;
}
@end
@implementation ZpCouncilVClrCenterAdvModel
+(NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{} ;
}
@end
@implementation ZpCouncilVClrNewsListModel
+(NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{} ;
}
@end
@implementation ZpCouncilVClrTopAdvModel
+(NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{} ;
}
@end
@implementation ZpCouncilVClrModel
+(NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{} ;
}
+ (ZpCouncilVClrModel *)createModelWith:(NSDictionary *)jsonParams
{
    NSError *error ;
    ZpCouncilVClrModel *jsonModel = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[self class] fromJSONDictionary:jsonParams error:&error];
    if( error ){
        return nil ;
    }
    return jsonModel ;
}

@end
```

You can see a method :

```
[ + (ZpCouncilVClrModel *)createModelWith:(NSDictionary *)jsonParams ]
```

In the Method , I use MTLJSONAdapter class convert json dictionary to a ZpCouncilVClrModel* object .
you can see the code

```
ZpCouncilVClrModel *jsonModel = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[self class] fromJSONDictionary:jsonParams error:&error];
```

But !

I check the result , I found the object(the name is jsonModel) exist , but jsonModel's property is nil !

Can you help me , Why the jsonModel's property is nil  ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Due to the naming of the classes your code is very hard to read.

Comment: [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:] returns nil, so you have to figure out what is going wrong in there. You pass it &error as error parameter, have you already checked the value of error after that method call?

Comment: Have u logged the NSDictionary which gets passed into the`modelOfClass: ...` method?